# Can someone help me extract this price from newegg using Python3? (HTML below)

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the 1097 from the html using python, but can't figure out how to do so. I have tried bs4 techniques with no luck.

```
<div class="grpPrimary" id="landingpage-price">
 <div data-reactid=".1">
  <div class="collapsed subscription-price student-purchase physical-subscription multiple-selections" data-reactid=".1.2">
   <div class="subscription-option" data-reactid=".1.2.0">
    <div class="product-accordion" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0" data-t-e-var78="$ - Group:Buy Used" data-t-events="A">
     <input aria-labelledby="radio_purchase" class="subscription-radio" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.0" name="purchase" title="subscription item" type="radio"/>
     <span data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.1">
     </span>
     <label data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.2">
      Buy Used
     </label>
     <ul class="price price-product-cells price-main-product price-preview" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3">
      <li class="price-was" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3.0">
      </li>
      <li class="price-map" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3.1">
      </li>
      <li class="price-current" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3.2">
       $
       <strong>
        1,097
       </strong>
       <sup>
        .97
       </sup>
      </li>
      <li class="price-save" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3.3">
       <noscript data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3.3.0">
       </noscript>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="grpPrimary" id="landingpage-price">
 <div data-reactid=".1">
  <div class="collapsed subscription-price student-purchase physical-subscription multiple-selections" data-reactid=".1.2">
   <div class="subscription-option" data-reactid=".1.2.0">
    <div class="product-accordion" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0" data-t-e-var78="$ - Group:Buy Used" data-t-events="A">
     <input aria-labelledby="radio_purchase" class="subscription-radio" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.0" name="purchase" title="subscription item" type="radio"/>
     <span data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.1">
     </span>
     <label data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.2">
      Buy Used
     </label>
     <ul class="price price-product-cells price-main-product price-preview" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3">
      <li class="price-was" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3.0">
      </li>
      <li class="price-map" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3.1">
      </li>
      <li class="price-current" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3.2">
       $
       <strong>
        1,097
       </strong>
       <sup>
        .97
       </sup>
      </li>
      <li class="price-save" data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3.3">
       <noscript data-reactid=".1.2.0.0.3.3.0">
       </noscript>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find("li", class_="price-current").get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
$1,097.97
```